# Getting error there exists no core with name in Solr

Tags: apache, tomcat, solr, lucene, solrnet

Currently I am facing an issue, when I am trying to import data from server where Tomcat is present, I am able to import the data,
but when I am trying to pass the URL from browser(local) it gives me error that
there exists no core with name in Solr.
 http://servername:portnumber/solr/Collection1/dataimport?command=full-import

when I am trying on above URL it gives me error HTTPStatus 404 and 
when I am trying 
 http://servername:portnumber/solr/#/Collection1/dataimport?command=full-import

it throws me error that there exists no core with name in Solr.

Please help.

Comment: check if your core is loaded properly or not ... you can paste solr logs here

Comment: The #-part of an URL is only available client side and for the javascript - this is used by the Admin UI to keep state and load the correct sub page. Giving it arguments will do nothing - but you can try the DataImport page under the core admin and see if the state says anything useful there.